# Золотой знак "Фанатик" - больше половины было пройдено и вдруг сброшен счетчик

Tags: поддержка, знаки, страница-учётной-записи

У меня сбросился знак ***Фанатик*** на пройденной границе более чем в половину!
Возможно я забыл заглянуть на сайт, но вдруг появилось желание проверить, так ли это...Думаю, что произошло это в минувшие выходные, когда мобильное приложение не выдало мне результата, а компьютера не было под рукой. В условиях получения знака написано:

> Посещать сайт ежедневно в течение 100 дней подряд. (Учет дней по UTC.)

Есть ли возможность взглянуть на временные интервалы посещения мною сайта **Stack Overflow на Русском**? Я же могу здесь обсудить этот вопрос? :)

Comment: `Я же могу здесь обсудить этот вопрос?` - да, именно для этого и предназначена Мета )

Answer (score 14, accepted):

К сожалению, вы пропустили 29 мая. Посмотреть на календарь можно на [первой вкладке страницы вашей учетной записи](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m08PO.png) (нажмите на ссылку `"на сайте ххх дней, из них ууу подряд"`)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может это модераторская плюшка? В упор не вижу :(

Comment: @ReinRaus, только на своей страничке работает :)

Comment: @ReinRaus, я тоже не нашел пока...

Comment: @ReinRaus нажмите на ссылку )

Comment: Блин. Разные профили. Некрасиво :( Сделайте скрин, как у меня :)

Comment: Круто! Спасибо! :)

Comment: @ReinRaus спасибо, так значительно понятнее стало.

Comment: @DenisBubnov намекну, что на Мете тоже возможно получить Фанатика. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, это я знаю :) читал как-то правила, когда первый раз заходил

Comment: @ReinRaus с вашим календарём теряет смысл указание на то, что пропущено 29 мая )

Comment: Ну блин :( ну сделайте нормальный скрин :)

Comment: "Думаю, что произошло это в минувшие выходные, когда мобильное приложение не выдало мне результата, а компьютера не было под рукой."